# Using Phalcon Tags to dynamically load CSS and Javascript files

Tags: php, phalcon

I guess this question might have the same outcome as [How do I use "Main Layout" views in a multi module Phalcon application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12951048/how-do-i-use-main-layout-views-in-a-multi-module-phalcon-application)

My **Main Layout** view has the basic html structure of my entire app and I'm using the **controller layout** view to present the content of that controller. I believe I am doing it right so far?

But now I have a problem with needing to load specific JS and CSS files relevant to just that module controller in my **Main Layout** view.

Currently I am loading all CSS and JS in my **Main Layout** file but this completely goes against the multi module approach. Each module should be able to load css/js files without having to modify a core layout file.

Ideally I would love to follow the same approach as setting page titles

**Controller:**
Phalcon\Tag::setStylesheetLink("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rosario", false);

**Views:** echo Phalcon\Tag::getStylesheetLink();

Is there any other way I can accomplish this that I might be missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the moment there is no way to create some sort of ordering function (stylesheets are printed out with the order you set them) or a collection facility where you just add stylesheets to `\Phalcon\Tag::stylesheetLink()` and they can be printed out.

However you can achieve what you need with a custom class as follows:

In your config.ini you have this section

```
[resource]
css.bootstrap = "/public/css/bootstrap.css"
css.index     = "/public/css/index.css"
css.about     = "/public/css/about.css"
css.contact   = "/public/css/contact.css"
```

Create a class `\MyApp\Tag`

```
namespace MyApp;

class Tag
{
    private $_css = array();

    public function add($css)
    {
        $this->_css[$css] = true;
    }

    public function remove($css)
    {
        $this->_css[$css] = false;
    }

    public function clear()
    {
        $this->_css = array();
    }

    public function generate()
    {
        $config = \Phalcon\DI::getDefault()->get('config');
        $output = '';

        foreach ($this->_css as $css => $active)
        {
            if ($active)
            {
                if (isset($config->resource->css->$css))
                {
                    $output .= \Phalcon\Tag::stylesheetLink($config->resource->css->$css);
            }
        }

        return $output;
    }
}
```

Then in your controller you can just do something like:

```
$style = new \MyApp\Tag();
$style->add('bootstrap');
$style->add('about');

$this->view->setVar('stylesheets', $style->generate();
```

and in your view:

```
<?php echo $stylesheets; ?>
```

Comment: Hello Nikolaos, Sorry for taking so long to respond, I've been juggling projects. Unfortunately I am having issues with calling the class. Should i be adding it to the DI? Currently I am just calling it as you have above and my error is: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'MyApp\Tag' not found. I have obviously substituted "MyApp" for the name of my app but I can't think of what else I am doing wrong?

Comment: @Tim You will need to register the `MyApp` namespace so that it can be found. You can name it whatever you like really. If you add it in the DI container all you will have to do is: `$obj = \Phalcon\DI::getDefault()->get('mytag')`. If time is not an issue here you might want to wait until the beginning of December, where 0.7 is out. This functionality is included in that version.

Comment: Hi Nikolaos, I found the problem, I wasn't registering the namespaces in the autoloader. Fantastic that this functionality will be built in soon!! Quick question to help me learn. I am getting another Fatal error in the class above, "Using $this when not in object context" on this line: foreach ($this->_css as $css => $active). I don't understand what is going on here? I would really appreciate your insights.

Comment: Ack! My bad. $this does not exist in static classes. Let me change the code real quick.

Comment: @Tim Corrected. The `generate` function should not be static.

Comment: Hi Nikolaos, Thankyou for that! No more errors :) However unfortunately I'm still not getting an output of the generate function. I have printed out my array from $config = \Phalcon\DI::getDefault()->get('config'); and I can see my values however I can see the next condition is not true. if (isset($config->resource->$css)). When I echo out $config->resource->css I get the following message: PHP Notice:Undefined property: Phalcon\Config::$master in /Users/tim/Applications/myApp/core/library/Tag.php on line 31. "master" is the name of the css file I am passing through. Hope this makes sense :)

Comment: @Tim Sorry about that. There was an error with the isset and the Tag functions when referencing the css object. It should be `$config->resource->css->$css` and not `$config->resource->$css`. This way it matches the config.ini files. Let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way you can manually manipulate the order of your js and css file assets.

First, when adding css and js paths in the controllers, use the automatic Phalcon\Assets\Collection containers to store your ad-hoc assets:

```
$this->assets->addJs('js/bootstrap-multiselect.js');
$this->assets->addCss('css/bootstrap-multiselect.css');
```

In your custom BaseController from which all your controllers extend, add an afterExecuteRoute() public method:

```
/**
 * stuff to do after a route has been executed
 * this is where we attach standard js and css assets
 * */
public function afterExecuteRoute(){
    // wait to rebuild assets until after the dispatcher is finished
    if( ! $this->dispatcher->isFinished() ){
        return;
    }
    ...
}
```

Once we're sure the current route is finished executing, we can pull the ad-hoc assets from the automatic js and css collections in the Phalcon\Assets\Manager, append them to our list of common asset files, order and dedup them, and then put them into new custom collections:

```
// get list of js files added to the standard js collection
$append_js = array();
forEach( $this->assets->getJs() as $js){
    $append_js[] = $js->getPath();
}
// declare paths to common js assets
$js_assets = array(
    'js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js',
    'js/jquery-ui.min.js',
    'js/bootstrap.min.js',
);
// merge common paths with ad-hoc paths
$js_assets = array_merge( $js_assets, $append_js );
$js_assets = array_unique( $js_assets ); // dedup
// add js assets to a new collection
$js_collection = $this->assets->collection('header_js');
forEach( $js_assets as $js_path ){
    $js_collection->addJs( $js_path );
}
```

Rebuilding the css assets into a new collection works the same way:

```
// get list of css files added to the standard css collection
$append_css = array();
forEach( $this->assets->getCss() as $css ){
    $append_css[] = $css->getPath();
}
// declare paths to common css assets
$css_assets = array(
    'css/jquery-ui.min.css',
    'css/jquery-ui.theme.min.css',
    'css/jquery-ui.structure.min.css',
    'css/bootstrap.min.css',
    'css/bootstrap-theme.min.css',
    'css/main.css',
);
// merge common paths with ad-hoc paths
$css_assets = array_merge( $css_assets, $append_css );
$css_assets = array_unique( $css_assets ); // dedup
// add css assets to a new collection
$css_collection = $this->assets->collection('header_css');
forEach( $css_assets as $css_path ){
    $css_collection->addCss( $css_path );
}
```

Finally, when you output your js and css assets in your template, output your new custom collections instead of the default collections that the Phalcon\Assets\Manager automatically created:

```
{{ getDoctype() }}
<html>
    <head>
        {{ tag.getTitle() }}
        {{ assets.outputCss( 'header_css' ) }}
        {{ assets.outputJs( 'header_js' ) }}
    </head>
```